# Retrieve data from session with PHPSESSID in Memcache

Tags: php, magento, session, memcached

I'm using memcahe/d to store sessions in magento, how do I retrieve the data stored inside a session where `PHPSESSID` is given?
Basically I need to do this:

```
$sessionFilePath =file_get_contents('path/to/session/sess_'.$_COOKIE['adminhtml']);
```

but with a system based on memcache/d storage instead of files.
Let's supposes that:

```
$session_save_path='tcp://10.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10'
```

is the `session.save_path` value

Comment: Hope this help you http://www.scriptcode.net/thread-13364-1-1.html

Comment: Yes, it absolutely works, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `$saveMethod` can only be equal to `memcache` or `memcached`(`memcached` should be support from Magento, but just in case..) (in a real enviroment it can be also `db` or `files`):

```
$locaXml = Mage::getBaseDir('etc').DS.'local.xml';
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load($locaXml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$entry = $xpath->query("//session_save");
foreach($entry as $ent){
     $saveMethod = trim($ent->nodeValue);
}
$saveMethod=(!empty($saveMethod))? $saveMethod:'files';

$entry = $xpath->query("//session_save_path");
foreach($entry as $ent){
    $session_path = $ent->nodeValue;
}
if(strpos($session_path,'?')!==false){
    $session_path=(explode('?',$session_path));
    $session_path=$session_path[0];
}

$session_path=explode(':',$session_path);
$port= $session_path[count($session_path)-1];
unset($session_path[count($session_path)-1]);
$host=implode(':',$session_path);
if($saveMethod=='memcache'){
    $m = new Memcache();
    $m = memcache_connect($host, $port);
}
else if($saveMethod=='memcached'){
    $m = new Memcached();
    $m->addServer($host, $port);
}

$session_data= $m->get({{PHPSESSID_VALUE}});
```